# `Selenium` get an error "WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'browser_name'"

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
class A():
    __init__():
        _option=ChromeOption()
        Chrome.__init__(self,options=_option)
```

then I find that:

```
Chrome.__init(self,options=_option):

super().init(……)
TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'browser_name'
```

I have check the version of my `selenium`.And it is "4.17.2"
I think it might be due to version conflict. But  I use "pip install selenium" to install this packet. And `webdriver` is is a subset of `selenium`. The corresponding version should be installed, so I don’t think there will be a version problem.`

I wonder how to solve it?